# How to avoid pass-through functions

Tags: c++, wrapper

A class I am currently working on has a member of some type that defines various functions. My class shall be a wrapper around this type for various reasons (e.g. make it thread-safe). Anyway, some of the type's functions can just be passed through, like the following:

```
class MyClass {
  // ... some functions to work with member_

  /* Pass through clear() function of member_ */
  void clear() {
    member_.clear()
  }

private:
  WrappedType member_;
};
```

This is not that bad, plus I get the flexibility of easily being able to add further functionality to `MyClass::clear()` in case I need it. Nevertheless, if I have a few of these pass-through functions, it bloats `MyClass` and for me makes it harder to read.

So I was wondering if there is a nice one-line-way (besides writing the upper definition into one line) of passing through `WrappedType`'s member functions, much like [making base class members available](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration#In_class_definition):

```
/* Pass through clear() in an easier and cleaner way */
using clear = member_.clear; // Unfortunately, this obviously doesn't compile
```

Comment: *"much like making **base class** members available"* - I wonder...

Comment: "*Nevertheless, if I have a few of these pass-through functions, it bloats MyClass and for me makes it harder to read*" - just implement them in `.cpp` file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Privately inherit from your base class and expose a subset of the interface with the `using` keyword:

```
class MyClass : private WrappedType 
{
public:
    using WrappedType::clear; 
};
```

Comment: Ok, now I understand @StoryTeller 's comment. I like the way this works, thanks.